# Changing elements position based on device screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I wanted to get an idea to solve a very specific issue I'm having. I have a web page design that basically shows something like this:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="home-img" class="col-6">
    ******An Image Goes Here******
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="locate" class="col-12">
           ******Content Here******
            </div>
            <div id="order" class="col-12">
           ******Content Here******
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to build the websites, classes above are just to kinda show how I kinda structured the design in my head, any changes to the structure are welcome so it can do what I need.

So I'm trying to think of a way to move the div with the `id="locate"` to be above the `id="home-img"` when I view the site on a phone or tablet but keep the `id="order"` below the `id="home-image"`.

I can't think of a way to set up the HTML so this is easier to do. I need the whole section to be like one row on desktop, with two columns, and on the second column 2 rows again; but when on mobile devices, to have the first column be on top of the first column of the first row.

**I want to display following structure on device screen.**

Desktop View.

```
----------------------------------------
|                      |  Content Here |
|  An Image Goes Here  |----------------
|                      |  Content Here |
----------------------------------------
```

Mobile View

```
------------------------
|  Content Here        |
------------------------
|  An Image Goes Here  |
------------------------
| Content Here         |
------------------------
```

Comment: you could use the [css grid system](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp). But I honestly dont know a solution with the grid system of bootstrap

Comment: I recommend you to look into Flexbox and media-queries. The `order` property from Flexbox can help you reorder elements. Media-queries are used to style your CSS based on the screen-size. [**See here**](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/xjaRNd) for an example where you can view and test the code yourself to see how it behaves.

Comment: @SirExotic I was actually looking into that property, but I don't think that'll work with how I've set up the HTML, in that case I would have to get rid of the "rows" and just have 3 flex items right? One for each 'div'?

Comment: Personally I would get rid of the Bootstrap rows, or use Bootstraps' [**reordering**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the **[`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)** property inside of a **[media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**.

The problem is that `#locate` is inside of a `.row` inside of a `.col-6`, and `order` will only apply to **sibling** elements. Thus, you must apply it to the `.col-6` itself. Fortunately, your `#home-img` has **[higher specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** than a simple `.col6`, so it will override the other selector.

This can be seen in the following, where `#locate` comes first for mobiles, and `#home-image` comes first for desktops (click `Run code snippet` and then `Full page` to see the desktop view):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-6 {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  #home-img {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div id="home-img" class="col-6">
    home-img
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="locate" class="col-12">
        locate
      </div>
      <div id="order" class="col-12">
        order
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And note that f you want the elements to stack on mobile, you can make use of `col-md-6` and `col-sm-12` instead of the simple `col-6` class:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-6 {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  #home-img {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div id="home-img" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    home-img
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="locate" class="col-12">
        locate
      </div>
      <div id="order" class="col-12">
        order
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, the "col-6" clases are just to show how it should look on desktop, at the moment the sm, md, lg and xl does not matter... The issue I see I have is that the way that I structured the HTML, if I want to move 'locate' I would have to move the whole div with the 2 rows... I what I need is to move just the 'locate' row...

I'm thinking I would have to get rid of the rows and just make 3 divs as flex items maybe? and try to position them I a way that resembles the above structure?

Comment: FYI, bootstrap has builtin [order classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order) if your gonna add 20 bootstrap classes, what's 1 more

Answer (score 0):

I think, have not possible to column move(order) from one row to another row. Here, You can try one Jugaad for that. You need to create twice `id="home-image"` column in both row. & then, You can hide & show it column in mobile or desktop screen as you want. please try following structure example as you want.

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="home-img" class="col d-none d-md-block"> ****** An Image Goes Here ****** </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="locate" class="col-12"> ****** Locate Content Here****** </div>
      <div id="home-img" class="col-12 d-block d-md-none"> ****** An Image Goes Here ****** </div>
      <div id="order" class="col-12"> ****** Order Content Here****** </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```